# How to create a crowd-sourced news platform, avoiding certain issues of existing news platforms?

Tags: participation

**The Problem:**
When I read/watch/listen to news in official media of various countries, I struggle with some issues:

- Strong overall focus on some topics, ignorance about other topics
- Priming, in the meaning of content is not written in a neutral wording
- Clickbaiting techniques
- Only half of the truth is being told
- Influenced by media owner/lobbyists/politicians
- Major part is 'negative' news (death, destructive events against humans, animals, nature, minorities etc.)
- Strict separation in good--bad without differentiation (while most of the time a topic has various viewpoints including positive and negative aspects at the same time)
- etc.

Based on this, I am thinking of how it can be possible to create a source of news that tries to avoid (at least most of) these issues.

*So **my question** is: How can it be done? What should this source of news look like, how should the research, contribution, writing and communication be done to accomplish this goal?*

My personal first and basic approach would include following (slightly controversial) points:

- Anyone can add content. This way we avoid that topics get ignored.
- A system to mark content as either being 'proven to be correct' or 'not (yet) verifiable'
- A system where only people known to contribute quality content are able to add content
- Possibility that people can edit and improve quality of existing content
- Maybe content has to be reviewed by a specified group of persons before it gets published to fulfill certain prerequisites.
- probably more points are important...

In other words, if this news platform would be online, I am thinking of some kind of combination of Stack Exchange and Wikipedia, with an active and heterogeneous community similar to big social media platforms.
Probably it is more difficult to create printed or TV/radio news that way.

It should both be possible to share regional news and at the same time news of events of global interest, while for the latter there should be ways that complex and complicated situations can be communicated continually and in a way that consumers can easily follow and understand at least the basic facts while always pointing out different perspectives, while it should still be fun to consume these news. (Is this even possible?)

Footnote: I hope this is the correct section for this question, if not, please help me to find a better place.